# how to use libreoffice flatpak headlessly

Tags: flatpak

I would like to use the libreoffice flatpak version to headlessly convert odt files to pdf.

So e.g.

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf ./somefile.odt
```

However, I want to use the flatpak version for this.

Comment: Does your command distinguish between flatpak and other versions of LO?

Comment: @Graham No, however, when involked on a system with libreoffice ppa installed, it uses this one. When involked on a system with only the flatpak version installed, it returns "libreoffice is not installed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable --headless --convert-to pdf ./somefile.odt
```

seems to work.

Hence, you can set an alias:

```
alias libreoffice="flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable"
```

and add it to your ~/.bashrc file and use libreoffice headlessly, like you are used to.

Comment: Could you help out [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1223104/248158)?

Comment: @DKBose I will share my experience, but i am not sure why I no longer have this problem.