# Kubuntu 18: can no longer change keyboard layout?

Tags: kubuntu

why is this dialog now read-only? I created two layouts, I could switch between them, I was able to add special chars by using right-alt, all this is now gone??????

[image]

totally disappointed in Kubuntu and Gnome.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. I had the same problem when connecting my keyboard via a displaylink adapter (usb type c dock) and powering this adapter after boot. Unfortunately (for you) I cannot replicate the behavior any more, as after a reboot it works like a charm. Is your system up-to-date? How is the keyboard connected? If it is a laptop, what model? Did you recently changed anything permission related (added a user, changed goup memberships etc.?

Comment: Can you change it if you try running from the command line? https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard

Comment: I will try. but this is the kind of dirty and unstable changes that I try to avoid. and I'm losing courage to file a bug, this is unacceptable nowadays that this kind of problem keeps popping up.

Comment: well, it works again. I suspect that system updates temporarily disabled that dialog until a reboot was done, I vaguely remember I had to postpone such a reboot and then forgot about it.